# How can I dynamically call a function from a method?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I have a method which takes some parameters from a file and does some different operations based on these parameters which are very dynamic by nature.And also this method should call different methods based on the parameters in the file. Can anybody suggest a better approach to do this ?

I am currently using this approach:

```
public void MethCaller(string FileName)
{
     //File operations to fetch parameters from file.

     if(some_parameter)
     {
         foo(other_parameter1,other_prameter2);
     }
     else
     {
         bar(other_parameter3,other_prameter4);
     }
}
```

Comment: IMO, that is pretty much the way to do it.

Comment: The parameters are all strings? Do all methods use the same number of strings?

Comment: please provide some information about foo and bar method

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to do something like this but each one is very situational so a lot more information is needed.

Comment: this will only work with same data types or parameters as Objects (pretty ugly), the most flexible is reflection, but its a powerful mechanism and most of the time can be (and should be) avoided, also IoC may help, or a factory pattern... many options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to suggest you to use the delegates if the methods `foo()` and `bar()` have same signature. There is also another way to do it. Hope this may help you.

declare some delegates for the methods

```
public delegate void foo_dele(type1 param1,type2 param2);
public delegate void bar_dele(type1 param1,type2 param2); // the arguments may vary.
```

now pass these to your `MethCaller()`

```
public void MethCaller(string FileName,foo_dele delfoo , bar_dele delbar)
{
     //File operations to fetch parameters from file.

     if(some_parameter)
     {
         delefoo = foo;
     }
     else
     {
         delebar = bar;
     }

     //call the dele if its got a reference to a method in it.
     if(!(delefoo.Target || delfoo.Method))
     {
        delfoo(pram1,param2);
        return;
     }
     delbar(param3,param4);
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Structurally that's the cleanest way to do it.  You could play around with reflection, a dictionary of delegates, etc. but there are pros/cons to all.

Essentially what you're building is a basic [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  Depending on how similar the actions are (type and order of parameters, etc.) there are different ways to approach it.

The *simplest* change would be to factor out that decision to another method:

```
public void MethodCaller(string FileName)
{
     //File operations to fetch parameters from file.
     Route(some_parameter,
           other_parameter1, other_parameter2,
           other_parameter3, other_parameter4);
}

public void Route(string some_parameter, parms object[] parameters)
{
     if(some_parameter)
     {
         foo(parameters[0],parameters[1]);
     }
     else
     {
         bar(parameters[2],parameters[3]);
     }
}
```

Of course from there you could move the call to a separate class, perhaps one that used a routing table (dictionary of string/delegate pairs), etc.  but nothing any *simpler* than what you have now.  All you're doing is addressing separation of concerns at the expense of simplicity.